# Why are the files not found I get ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone tell me why do the link tag not working? when i load it to the browser the console gives me an error saying

> GET file:///C:/Users/hp/Desktop/template%201/index.html/css/leon.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND??

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>leon template</title>
<!--main template css file-->
<link rel="styleSheet" href="css/leon.css">
<!-- render all elements normally -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<!--font-->
<link rel="preconnect"  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<!--css min file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css" />


</head>
```

Comment: Look in the network console. Likely you need /css or ../css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide wrong path, I don't know your structure but I guess your css folder is one above so it should be `"../css/leon.css"`

Comment: Please do not answer something that just needs one character - ESPECIALLY not when there already is the EXACT same comment. OP should fix the link and delete the question